# Deployment optimization failed due to an invalid assembly

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-3.0, blend

I've stuck with this error:

"Deployment optimization failed due to an invalid assembly. Rebuild your source projects and try again."

after I tried to bring DataTriggers from Blend into Windows Phone 7.1 project.

(System.Windows.Interactivity, Microsoft.Expressions.Interactions)

non of them use SHA2 algorithm which is not supported on Windows Phone 8 (deploying to Lumia 920)

Project runs in emulator just fine.

**UPDATE :** all files are hashed with 0x00008004 algorithm (SHA1)

Any help appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was Microsoft.Xna.Framework with wrong build architecture. I readded it with the right one and now it deploys fine!